# iPhone 7 paired with Windows 10 laptop (Dell Latitude 7480) yet "not supported"..?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, iphone

I am trying to **use Bluetooth from my iPhone to lock and unlock my Windows 10 laptop via Windows Hello** (lock when away, unlock when phone is beside laptop). Windows *says* the phone is "paired" but in the Action Center (pop-out column on the right) Bluetooth either toggles the device name (connected/disconnected) or simply shows it as "Not Connected." I have already [setup Dynamic Lock](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028111/windows-lock-your-windows-10-pc-automatically-when-you-step-away-from) and Windows shows the iPhone as paired and ready to lock/unlock the machine, but it does not work.

Is an iPhone 7 just not supported with Windows 10? The Windows Consumer Experience advertises the feature pretty heavily, so that would seem counter-intuitive. However, when I go into the iPhone's bluetooth settings and try to connect to "Dell-Win10Lptop" the iPhone throws an error message:

*Connection Unsuccessful

"Dell-Win10Lptop" is not supported.

Forget Device*

I've noticed there are 3 missing drivers in Win10:
- MAP MAS-iOS
- Wireless iAP
- Wireless iAP v2

However, I read elsewhere that these might not be obligatory?
The laptop is running Windows 10 v1809 (latest). The iPhone 7 is on iOS 12.1.4. I see my iPhone 7 listed in Win10 DevMgmt under Bluetooth. The Dell's Bluetooth adapter is listed as simply "Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)"

Comment: Are you sure your laptop has a BT device?  If it does what BT specifications (versions) does it support?  Instead of submitting a comment you should provide this required information in the body of your question.  I assume you have installed the required Windows Hello companion application on your phone?

Comment: Thanks, the Dell Latitude does support Bluetooth, yes. However, I was unaware of any app for iPhone - I don't see any such app in the app store..?

Comment: My apologies, it's on the Microsoft Store, so it's installed on the laptop, not the phone.  [According to this link, the functionality, was discontinued](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/companion-device-unlock)

Comment: Microsoft's own documentation does not even sync up, [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/302225/how-to-use-dynamic-lock-to-automatically-lock-your-windows-10-pc/), might be useful.

Comment: This [tool](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/90883/using-calibrating-dynamic-lock-windows-10-creators-update) might be helpful to diagnose what is going on with your iPhone/Laptop pairing.

Comment: Well, it has just started working somehow...not sure why/how, but I'll take it.